# Count Total Number of rows between two values when condition is met

Tags: pandas

I have the following data:

```
Date, Symbol, Close
2021-01-01, AAPL, 10
2021-01-02, AAPL, 12
2021-01-03, AAPL, 3
2021-01-01, MSFT, 12
2021-01-02, MSFT, 20
2021-01-03, MSFT, 12
2021-01-04, MSFT, 1
2021-01-05, MSFT, 2
2021-01-06, MSFT, 3
```

I'd like to count the number of rows it takes until the next 'Close' value is less than the current row 'Close' value within the 'Symbol' group

My goal is to understand how many days it takes to get a lower price.

Expected Output

```
Date, Symbol, Close, Output
2021-01-01, AAPL, 10, 2
2021-01-02, AAPL, 12,1
2021-01-03, AAPL, 3, NaN
2021-01-01, MSFT, 12, 3
2021-01-02, MSFT, 20, 1
2021-01-03, MSFT, 12, 1
2021-01-04, MSFT, 1, NaN
2021-01-05, MSFT, 2, 1
2021-01-06, MSFT, 1, NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy), computing a mask from the broadcasted difference of Close with itself, identifying the negative differences:

```
def n_to_lower(g):
    a = g.to_numpy()
    m = np.triu((a-a[:, None])<0)
    out = m.argmax(axis=1)-np.arange(len(a))
    return np.where(out>0, out, np.nan)

df['Output'] = df.groupby('Symbol')['Close'].transform(n_to_lower)
```

Output:

```
         Date Symbol  Close  Output
0  2021-01-01   AAPL     10     2.0
1  2021-01-02   AAPL     12     1.0
2  2021-01-03   AAPL      3     NaN
3  2021-01-01   MSFT     12     3.0
4  2021-01-02   MSFT     20     1.0
5  2021-01-03   MSFT     12     1.0
6  2021-01-04   MSFT      1     NaN
7  2021-01-05   MSFT      2     1.0
8  2021-01-06   MSFT      1     NaN
```

Warning: this computation takes `O(n²)` space for each group.

Intermediates (example on the MSFT group):

```
a = g.to_numpy()
# array([12,  3, 20, 12,  1,  2,  1])

m = np.triu((a-a[:, None])<0)
# array([[False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
#        [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
#        [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#        [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
#        [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
#        [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True],
#        [False, False, False, False, False, False, False]])

out = m.argmax(axis=1)-np.arange(len(a))
# array([ 1,  3,  1,  1, -4,  1, -6])

np.where(out>0, out, np.nan)
# array([ 1.,  3.,  1.,  1., nan,  1., nan])
```

---

Alternatively, same logic using [`expanding.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.apply.html):

```
def n_to_lower(g):
    if len(g)==1:
        return np.nan
    diff = (g.iloc[:-1]-g.iloc[-1])[::-1]
    m = diff<0
    idx = np.argmax(m)
    return idx+1 if m.iloc[idx] else np.nan

df['Output'] = (df.groupby('Symbol')['Close']
                  .transform(lambda g: g[::-1].expanding().apply(n_to_lower))
               )
```

This has the same complexity using less memory at once but being probably slower to compute.

###### timings

Provided example:

```
# numpy broadcasting
764 µs ± 42.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# expanding
3.11 ms ± 26.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

9000 rows (with 2 groups)

```
# numpy broadcasting
195 ms ± 2.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# expanding
1.96 s ± 52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

9000 rows (with 2000 groups)

```
# numpy broadcasting
157 ms ± 7.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# expanding
2.44 s ± 37.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Is there a vectorized version of this?

Comment: @greenguy this is vectorized

Comment: @mozway, a for loop within numba maybe?

Comment: @sammywemmy that's another possibility, I posted it as a separate answer since the logic is quite different

Comment: Thanks I went with the expanding method

Comment: @greenguy that's probably the worst of all 3 ;)

Comment: ha probably but I don't understand what the other two are doing exactly, still new to python

Comment: @mozway How could I modify the first solution count until the next 'Close' value is HIGHER than the current row 'Close' value

Comment: Just changing the condition from `<` to `>`?

Answer (score 1):

Using a loop and [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/):

```
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def n_to_lower(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
            if a[j]<a[i]:
                yield j-i
                break
        else:
            yield -1

out = df.groupby('Symbol')['Close'].transform(lambda g: n_to_lower(g.to_numpy()))

df['Output'] = out.where(out>0)
```

Output:

```
         Date Symbol  Close  Output
0  2021-01-01   AAPL     10     2.0
1  2021-01-02   AAPL     12     1.0
2  2021-01-03   AAPL      3     NaN
3  2021-01-01   MSFT     12     3.0
4  2021-01-02   MSFT     20     1.0
5  2021-01-03   MSFT     12     1.0
6  2021-01-04   MSFT      1     NaN
7  2021-01-05   MSFT      2     1.0
8  2021-01-06   MSFT      1     NaN
```

Timings:

```
# example
682 µs ± 15.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# 9000 rows (2 groups)
11.5 ms ± 507 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# 9000 rows (2000 groups)
141 ms ± 15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```